# trying to learn webDriverIO

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm currently using UDEMY to teach myself WebDriverIO. At the moment I'm in the fundamental stages of my journey. While watching a course I seem to have stumbled upon a problem. - I'm currently trying to have my code load up craigslist, pause for x amount of time, then notify me of any 'li' on the webpage. my code is able to find the website but it isn't able to find a 'li' on the website. any suggestions as to why my code doesn't work?

```
it('Load example Website', () => {
  browser.url('https://www.example.com');
  browser.pause(10000);
  expect(browser).toHaveUrl('https://www.example.com');
 });

describe('Craigslist website loads up', () => {
  it('load Craigslist ', () => {
    browser.url('https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/');
    browser.pause(20000);
    expect(browser).toHaveUrl('https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/');
    expect(browser).toHaveTitle('craigslist');
  });
});


it('Craigslist website, li should be visible', () => {
  // GET Selector and save it to a variable
  // do assertion
  const li = $('li');
  expect(li).toBeVisible();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Every test is and should be independent, that is you are not on any site in this test:

```js
it('Craigslist website, li should be visible', () => {
  const li = $('li');
  expect(li).toBeVisible();
});
```

You need to go to the site like you do in the previous two tests.

Better way is to use [beforeTest hook](https://webdriver.io/docs/options/#beforetest).

Comment: Hi Pavelsaman, thanks for replying. After looking at my previous I was able to figure out my problem with your help. Cheers ~ Zack